# Where to find Fcurve's 'enable modifiers' (wrench) attribute with python

Tags: python, dopesheet, fcurves

As i'm working with custom fcurves in the Dopesheet, i wanted to use that little wrench icon to control something.

[image]

It was easy to find `fcurve[0].lock` and `fcurve[0].mute` attributes which were booleans as expected, but this one seems undocumented.

Any suggestion is truly welcome !

Comment: As with many of the area UI items, this one isn't exposed through the Python interface.  The best you can do is use the mute value of each of the fcurve's modifiers.